# How to remove DOM Elements from XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Following is my XML File content

[image]

Now I want to remove < text > element from xml, how can I do it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load("XML FILE");
$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('text');
foreach ($list as $domElement){
    //Code to remove current text element... 
}
```

Comment: `$domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);`

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the manual? You can use `removeChild`. the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) has an example.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('book.xml');

$book = $doc->documentElement;

// we retrieve the chapter and remove it from the book
$chapter = $book->getElementsByTagName('chapter')->item(0);
$oldchapter = $book->removeChild($chapter);

echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```